# Terminal displays no bash prompt on login

Tags: git, bash, terminal

After multiple restarts, my terminal displayed just the "last logged in on -timestamp-

I see a cursor, I can type, but I see no prompt. It pops up here and there, but I cannot get it to do anything. The familiar $ bash prompt, gone.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had somehow initialized a .git folder in my home directory. If this happens to you, just wait until you get the prompt and do

```
~ $ rm -r .git
```

or go into Finder, Nautilus or whatever your gui file browser is, display hidden files (ctrl h on Ubuntu) and chuck the .git folder and you are good to go.

Comment: This only applies if you didn't intentionally make your home directory a Git repository.

Comment: Since when is `git` constantly running looking over your shoulder? My home directory has been a `git` repository for a long time, and `git` doesn't notice anything unless I tell it to notice something. I would suspect something else in `.profile`, `.bashrc`, etc... Unless you have some per-prompt `git` processing that runs every time you hit the return key or something...

Comment: I might be wrong, but this happened to me yesterday, and thought I would share the solution. I was quite frightening and I found nothing on any forum about it. It was also one of those difficult to google problems. Deleting the git folder got things working again.